# ajax url always redirect to index

Tags: php, ajax, google-app-engine

I have a script to load combobox value base on another combobox value. there is no problem at localhost but when i upload my script to google cloud my script not working.

here is my ajax file

```
$.ajax({                                      
  url: '<?= PATH ?>/modules/json/product/getCategory.php',                         
  data: "test="+selectVal,                                                     
  type:'post',                     
  success: function(data)    
  {                 
    var i;              
    var product_category_info = document.getElementById("product_category_info");   
    var length = product_category_info.options.length;
    for (i = length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
      product_category_info.options[i] = null;
    }
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = '';
    option.text = '';
    product_category_info.add(option);
    for(var k in data){                     
      var option = document.createElement('option');
      option.value = k;
      option.text = data[k]['product_category_description'];
      product_category_info.add(option);
    }
  }
});
```

and here is my app.yaml

```
runtime: php73

handlers:
- url: /resources/
  static_dir: public/resources

- url: /resources/images
  static_dir: public/resources/images

- url: /library/images
  static_dir: public/library/images

- url: /(.+\.(gif|png|jpg))$
  static_files: \1
  upload: .+\.(gif|png|jpg)$
```

I'm really sure that I need to add something to app.yaml file but I don't know what should I add. I've tried to add

```
- url: myajaxpath.php
    script: myajaxpath.php
```

but still not working. please help me

Comment: Hi there, what is the error message you received? `404 not found`? Or is it a deployment issue?
Is it flex or standard service? Does the ajax file run and fail(perhaps relative paths) or is it not found? What is your folder structure when running the code locally? Is your issue related to this `<?= PATH ?>/modules/json/product/getCategory.php'`? If so, have you already tried specifying the absolute path?

Comment: hi, thank you for your reply, I have solve the problem by changing my ajax url path so the url will access index and index will redirect it to the function I use. The problem is because gcloud with php 7.x always route your app through index first and my ajax url code access the file directly.